# How to add a button or a link to re-direct to another model inside a tree view odoo 12?

Tags: odoo

I've tried to do giving widget ='url' in XML,
Actually what I'm trying to do is, I have a model named A and B, A has the relation to B as One2many. So I wanna load to the Model B from the tree view in the Model A.(like from a form view when I click a button it loads the model B, like that from the tree view can I achieve?

```
class test(models.Model):
    _name = 'consultation'

    test_id = fields.One2many('case.sheet','consultation_id',string='Case Sheet Id')
```

Comment: You may have a look into a nice OCA module: https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/12.0/web_tree_many2one_clickable

Comment: seems like a good reference,thannk you and you are awesome .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on a line in the tree view, Odoo will load the `default` form view to show the corresponding line record.

The `url` widget uses the field value as the value of `href` attribute ( if the we do not specify the `text` attribute it will use the field value).

`button` element can be a children element of the [list view](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html#lists) and to show a custom form view different from the one used in the tree view, you can add a button of type object in the tree view of the `test_id` field and declare a method with the same name in `case.sheet`.

***Example:***

Declare the method in `case.sheet` model:

```py
class CaseSheet(models.Model):
    _name = 'case.sheet'

    @api.multi
    def open_form_view(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        form_view = self.env.ref('MODULE.XML_VIEW_ID')
        return {
            'name': _('Case sheet'),
            'res_model': 'case.sheet',
            'res_id': self.id,
            'views': [(form_view.id, 'form'), ],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Add the button to the tree view:

```xml
<field name="test_id">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        <field name="name"/>
        <button name="open_form_view" type="object" string="View" class="oe_highlight"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: Thank  you for replying again.,Ive Only now learnt that we can add button in tree view.Now i got the idea thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a button and an action. First, you need to add a button in your tree view:

```html
<button type="object" name="go_to_model_B" string="To Model B" icon="fa-search"/>
```

Here the **name** prop is a method in your model A (the **icon** prop is optional but I think it looks better). The method goes something like this:

```py
# Method in Model A
def go_to_model_B(self):
    name_form = _('FORM B')
    return {
        'name': NAME_FORM,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'MODEL.B',
        'res_id': self.consultation_id.id,  # Reference to the other model
        'target': 'new',
        'view_id': self.env.ref(
            'FORM_VIEW_MODEL_B').id,
        'context': {} # Optional
    }
```

Maybe you want to open the form in a new tab, here is another option:

```py
import werkzeug.utils

def go_to_model_B(self):
    url_base = "{}/web?&#id={}&view_type=form&model={}&action={}'"
    action = "MODULE.ACTION_FORM_MODEL_B" # Name of the action defined in some XML
    model_name = "MODEL.B"
    target_record_id = self.consultation_id.id
    url = url_base.format(domain, target_record_id, model_name, action)
    return werkzeug.utils.redirect(url)
```

Another way to do this is using ir.actions.act_url:

```py
 def go_to_model_B(self):
    return {
        'name': "TO MODEL B"
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': url,  # The url is the same as above
        'target': 'new'
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for responding,Thankful to learnt it from you.